# Angular 2 add debounce function directly to pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, debouncing, angular2-pipe

I've written a pipe that filters out an array of objects based on a given query. It works great but what I'd like to do is add a debounce function to this pipe directly, instead of adding it to the input's keyup event, if possible.

I've been looking around for a solution but can't seem to find anything that's specific to what I'm looking for.

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterBy'
})

export class FilterByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args: string[]): any[] {

    if (!args[0]) {
      return value;
    }
    else if (value) {

      return value.filter(item => {

        // TODO: Allow args[1] to be null, therefore searching in all object properties
        if ((typeof item[args[1]] === 'string' || item[args[1]] instanceof String) && (item[args[1]].toLowerCase().indexOf(args[0].toLowerCase()) !== -1)) {
          return true;
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how I would implement this in this pipe?

Comment: Where you want to apply the debounce

Comment: @PatrickJane Not sure where it needs to go.

Comment: Why do u need the debounce?

Comment: @PatrickJane So it doesn't filter a list of potentially hundreds of items on every keystroke..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debounce or delay functions are async, in this case you need to return a promise or an observable from your pipe and use the async pipe. I created a simple example to show you how to do that with observable.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'myfilter'
})

export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items, filterBy) {
      const filteredItems = items.filter(item => item.title.indexOf(filterBy.title) !== -1);
      return Observable.of(filteredItems).delay(1000);
    }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of items | myfilter:filterBy | async">
         {{item.title}}
        </li>
      </ul>

      <input type="text" (input)="filter($event)">

    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  filterBy;
  constructor() {
    this.filterBy = {title: 'hello world'};
    this.items = [{title: 'hello world'}, {title: 'hello kitty'}, {title: 'foo bar'}];
  }

  filter($event) {
    this.filterBy = {title: $event.target.value}
  }
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0au3ZkuoaPSpyUXjNOgl?p=preview)

Comment: Doesn't this just add a delay between the input and the output rather than debouncing (wait x amount after the last input before processing)?

Comment: How can we estimate the delay value ? lets say I have 10 000 items (less or more in my case)

Comment: I've just tested this solution but it does not speed up the filter in my case, I don't know how to approach this problem.